# how to use vscode snippets to generate my own return code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

if I have a struct, like

```
type Person struct{
   Name string
   some fields here
}
```

how to generate code like this when I create a method

```
func (p *Person) foo() (Person,error){
   ...

   return Person{},err
}
```

and do need some snippets like this when  I want to catch some error

```
    if err != nil {
        return Person{}, err   // some struct or []struct here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start using snippets in VS Code. Ensure "editor.tabCompletion" is enabled in settings.json (or use Ctrl+Space).

There are [list of all snippets](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/blob/master/snippets/go.json), you could add a new throug request for feature.

For example use "iferr" to generate error check. For sure it will not grab the name of your struct, but at least it will help you a bit :)

If it is ok for you to have snippet locally, just go to File -> Preferences -> User snippets. Choose GO language and insert yours.